# jQuery object data odd even value to display in select odd as option value, even as option text

Tags: jquery, object

```
g_regions = ["USD", "North America", "EUR", "Europe", "GBP", "United Kingdom", "USD", "Asia & Pacific", "USD", "Australasia", "USD", "South America", "USD", "Africa"];
```

Above values are display in `select dropdown` using **jQuery**.

for Eg: output like this

```
<select>
  <option value="USD">North America</option>
  <option value="EUR">Europe</option>
  <option value="GBP">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="USD">Asia & Pacific</option>
  <option value="USD">Australasia</option>
  <option value="USD">South America</option>
  <option value="USD">Africa</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('body').append('<select />');

var g_regions = ["USD", "North America", "EUR", "Europe", "GBP", "United Kingdom", "USD", "Asia & Pacific", "USD", "Australasia", "USD", "South America", "USD", "Africa"];

for(var i=0; i<g_regions.length; i=i+2){
  $('select').append(`<option value="${g_regions[i]}">${g_regions[i+1]}</option>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Loop through the array with `step increment of 2` & then append `option` to `select`.

I've used `ES6` version along with `backtick` instead of single or double quotes & `${}`.

`${}` is used for assigning value, inside the curly braces you need have a variable.

Reference:- [JavaScript-Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what is the purpose of `${g_regions[i]}` ? how's it interprets? add that too

Comment: This is assign value or replace with the value, its a `ES6` standard to use variable inside backtick